# Why does $Y'=\Theta+(W/3)$ have the same estimation and MSE as $Y=3\Theta+W$?

Tags: bayesian, estimation

This is from MIT's 6.431x.

> For the model $X=\Theta+W$, and under the usual independence and normality assumptions for $\Theta$ and $W$, the mean squared error (MSE) of the LMS estimator is
> $$\frac{1}{(1/\sigma_0^2)+(1/\sigma_1^2)}$$
> where $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$ are the variances of $\Theta$ and $W$, respectively.

> Suppose now that we change the observation model to
> $Y=3\Theta+W$. In some sense the “signal" $\Theta$ has a stronger presence, relative to the noise term $W$, and we should expect to obtain a smaller mean squared error. Suppose $\sigma_0^2=\sigma_1^2=1$. The mean squared error of the original model $X=\Theta+W$ is then $1/2$.

> Find the mean squared error of the new model $Y=3\Theta+W$ by thinking of an alternative observation model in which you observe $Y'=\Theta+(W/3)$.

I don't at all understand the solution (see below), in fact I got stuck immediately at the first sentence: Since $Y'$ is just $Y$ scaled by a factor of $1/3$, $Y'$ carries the same information as $Y$, so that $E[\Theta|Y]=E[\Theta|Y']$.

Why does $Y'$ carry the same info as $Y$? Because I would have expected that because it is scaled by a factor of $1/3$, the spread would be smaller, which contributes to a smaller MSE? (And by the same token, a smaller estimate as well)

---

Solution:

Since $Y'$ is just $Y$ scaled by a factor of $1/3$, $Y'$ carries the same information as $Y$, so that $E[\Theta|Y]=E[\Theta|Y']$. Thus, the alternative observation model $Y'=\Theta+(W/3)$ will lead to the same estimates and will have the same mean squared error as the unscaled model $Y=\Theta+W$. In the equivalent model $Y'$, we have a noise variance of $1/9$ and therefore the mean squared error is $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1/9}}=\frac{1}{10}$$.

Comment: If $f$ is any (Borel measurable) injective function, then for any $Y$ with finite expectation, one has $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y\mid f(X))$. For more you should read into something along the lines of "conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: The basic idea is as follows. Assume $E Y^2 <\infty$ and $X$ is some random  variable defined on the same probability space. It is a fact that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, which are those random variables with finite second moment. $\sigma(X) = \{Z\in L^2: Z = f(X), f\text{ measurable}\}$ is a closed linear subspace of $L^2$. Thus Hilbert space theory says that $Y$ can be uniquely decomposed as $Y = \text{projection}+\text{error}$ where projection$\in \sigma(X)$ and error is orthogonal to $\sigma(X)$. We use the notation $E(Y\mid X)$ to denote the projection.

Comment: This projection can be uniquely extended to $L^1$, those random variables with finite first moment. But the point is that conditional expectation in the $L^2$ case can be thought of as projection. Since $\sigma(X) = \sigma(f(X))$ for any injective $f$, the projections $E(Y\mid X)$ and $E(Y\mid f(X))$ must be the same. More details can be found in Ch.8 of Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability 3e. The more standard treatment, which uses Radon-Nikodym can be found, for example, here: https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf (or really any probability textbook)

Comment: @AndrewZhang I am sorry but I only have a basic calculus background and this is my first intro to probability, could there be a simpler explanation for this?

Comment: In English, when you do conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X)$, you are basically trying to use $X$ to make the best prediction possible for $Y$. Put another way, you have all the information $X$ provides you at your disposal. Now, consider $E(Y\mid f(X))$ where $f$ is injective. Then $f(X)$ provides the same information as $X$ since $f$ is injective. Thus $E(Y\mid f(X)) = E(Y\mid X)$. Alternatively, you can write out the integral $E(\Theta \mid Y/3)$ and using change of variables, you will see it is the same as $E(\Theta \mid Y)$.